# Can not creat consumer with kafka cmd in windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have an environment problem. 
I want using zookeeper and Kafka cluster to solve my problem.

My zookeeper version is 3.4.12 and Kafka is 2.12-2.1.0

I also change the zoo.cfg in zookeeper.

```
dataDir=D:/WEBSOCKET/zookeeper-3.4.12/data
```

and server.properties in kafka.

```
log.dirs=D:/WEBSOCKET/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/logs
```

I see all the tutorial and do it the exact same way.
And also usgin kafka open zookeeper.

this is my command:

1) open zookeeper (zkServer.cmd)

2) in kafka

.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

3) create topic

.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic hello

4) create a producer

.\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --topic hello

5) create a consumer

.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --topic hello

when I get in step 5, I always fail.
zookeeper will give me a lot of console like :

```
 WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:55192
```

and

```
2019-01-08 17:05:24,822 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:50874 (no session established for client)
2019-01-08 17:05:25,783 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:56089
```

I don't know how to fix it. I google for two days...

when I open my Kafka with step 2, my zookeeper some times doesn't hvae any response or shows me this:

```
 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@596] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000058f8960000 type:multi cxid:0x36 zxid:0x69 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election
```

I also google this, but not helpful.

I set this in kfaka before:
advertised.host.name = localhost 
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092

my host have set 
127.0.0.1       localhost

please help me create local server I want to coding my project..

thank you read all.

Comment: "when I get in step 5, I always fail" What happens? Do you see any errors? Can you paste the logs of the `kafka-console-consumer.bat` tool with `TRACE` enabled?

Comment: You do not need to edit your hosts file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Producers and consumers need to use port 9092 (Kafka)

You are seeing Zookeeper logs and errors because you are trying to use `bootstrap-server` or `broker-list` and port 2181 (Zookeeper)

Check again [the quickstart guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)

Comment: Thanks. I add a comment   --from-beginning and it will succeed.
But I don't know why, because I don't want to get all message...
I want to use Kafka to be a socket server push message but not get everything in connect.

Comment: If you don't want actual persistent storage where you are able to get all the messages, then Kafka is not the tool for you. It is much more than a simple socket server. Sounds like you could rather use Socket.IO or ZeroMQ for eample

Comment: Otherwise, you must first start the consumer and **then** the producer (swap steps 4 and 5), and new messages will be seen by the consumer

Comment: I want persistent storage in my DB, but I have a lot of tomcats to use socket. I google and it says Kafka can do Subscription/publishing mode.and its a good way to make different message can send all of the tomcats so I decided to use Kafka, I also see the Rabbitmq too.
now I swap steps 4 and 5 . it dosesn't work.

it will show 
 ERROR Error when sending the message to topic linlin8 with key: null, value: 3 bytes with error
and I rebuild again, sometimes succeed sometimes fail.

Comment: Tomcat can use REST API or raw TCP socket on its own (or gRPC server), and you can write to DB with that. Kafka is not a socket to run within Tomcat, and your Tomcat app would need a consumer client within it, not using the console consumer.... Anyway, again, you need to correct the ports, but works fine for me, so I'm not sure what you are doing differently. Make sure you are typing messages into the producer and get `>` prompt

Comment: thank you very much.when I create a consumer my localhost:2181 is wrong, I change it to 9092 and its success, and the tomcat cluster socket issue. I google the rabbitmq and Kafka, 90% say Kafka is better than rabbitmq, so I using Kafka to solve my problem.
My think is when I just sub the topic and if have the message I will do my logic, your session message in my tomcat I will send a message to, if not I don't sent.

Comment: Kafka doesn't fit every use case, though. It is "differernt" than RabbitMQ, not necessarily better, depending on how well you are actually able to maintain it, just as any other server/database tool